# Testing object properties as roughly equal

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test if object properties are roughly equal to expected value:

```
const compare = (triangle: Triangle, type: string) => {
    const expected = eval(type)
    const closeTo = (expected:number , precision = 2) => ({
      asymmetricMatch: (actual: number) => Math.abs(expected - actual) < Math.pow(10, -precision) / 2
    });
    
    expect(triangle.sides).toMatchObject({
      a: closeTo(expected.a,3),
      b: closeTo(expected.b,3),
      c: closeTo(expected.c,3)
    })
    expect(triangle.angles).toMatchObject({
      A: closeTo(expected.A,3),
      B: closeTo(expected.B,3),
      C: closeTo(expected.C,3)
    })
```

It works, but when values don't match I get object comparing received value to object:

```
Object {
    -   "A": Object {
    -     "asymmetricMatch": [Function asymmetricMatch],
    -   },
    +   "A": 45.06,
        "B": Object {
    -     "asymmetricMatch": [Function asymmetricMatch],
    -   },
    -   "C": Object {
          "asymmetricMatch": [Function asymmetricMatch],
        },
    +   "C": 59.94,
      }
```

How can I get expected value in logs and actually read what the problem is?